# Custom Context Menu splits on columns

Tags: css, tampermonkey

I coded a simple context menu which appears after right clicking on a `li` of an unordered list.

It works fine, but it looks weird and floats with the html.

[image]

It should rather look like this:

[image]

I really hope someone can help me to understand whats going on. I need the context menu to appear right below the `li`.

Please add this script to your `tampermonkey` engine and try it out on [this page](https://bs.to/andere-serien):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Burning Series
// @namespace    http://bs.to/
// @version      1.0
// @description  -
// @author       Me
// @match        https://bs.to/andere-serien
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('.contextMenuParent { position: relative;  }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenuContainer { position: absolute; background: gray; z-index: 100; -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu { display: grid; padding: 4px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;  color: black; }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu li:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }');

var contextMenuLinks =
    "<li class='contextMenu01'>A</li>"+
    "<li class='contextMenu02'>B</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu03'>C</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu04'>D</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu05'>E</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu06'>F</li>";


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div.genre > ul > li").each(function(i, obj) {

        $(this).addClass("contextMenuParent");

        $(this).contextmenu(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".contextMenuContainer").remove();

            $(this).append("<div class='contextMenuContainer'><ul class='contextMenu'>" + contextMenuLinks + "</ul></div>");

        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".contextMenu li", function() {
        var c = $(this).attr("class");
        alert("test:" + c);

        var title = $(this).closest(".contextMenuParent").find("a").attr("title");

        $(".contextMenuContainer").remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: Does this by any chance uses CSS Columns?

Comment: Im not sure, but I provided any code which I use. I hope you can figure it out.

Comment: The website looks like it uses columns and I strongly feel that's messing up with your context menu...

Comment: It uses many `ul` and `li`. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Agreed you have given all that you have - as I said you, I guess you didn't notice - it depends on the website, which uses CSS columns, that's messing it up. Remove the CSS columns in the website.

Comment: Im not sure how I can remove these "CSS columns", it is not my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `fixed` positioning and calculate the coordinates via javascript. I also added a scroll event to `$(window)`, so you can recalculate the coordinates and move the fixed element.

`fixed` means exact x-y coordinates **on the document** so you need to subtract the `$(window).scrollTop()` from the position to get the screen coordinates, and also add the `height` of the `li`, so it comes exactly below the element (not overlapping it).

Here's the code, I tested it with Tampermonkey and it works fine.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Burning Series
// @namespace    http://bs.to/
// @version      1.0
// @description  -
// @author       Me
// @match        https://bs.to/andere-serien
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('.contextMenuParent { position: relative;  }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenuContainer { position: absolute; background: gray; z-index: 100; -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu { display: grid; padding: 4px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;  color: black; }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu li:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }');

var contextMenuLinks =
    "<li class='contextMenu01'>A</li>"+
    "<li class='contextMenu02'>B</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu03'>C</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu04'>D</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu05'>E</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu06'>F</li>";


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div.genre > ul > li").each(function(i, obj) {

        $(this).addClass("contextMenuParent");

        $(this).contextmenu(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".contextMenuContainer").remove();

            $(this).append("<div class='contextMenuContainer'><ul class='contextMenu'>" + contextMenuLinks + "</ul></div>");

            // Calculate the offset coordinates and set CSS rules
            var off = $(this).offset();
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(this).find(".contextMenuContainer").css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'left': off.left + 'px',
                'top': (off.top + $(this).outerHeight() - scroll) + 'px'
            });

        });
    });

    // Move the menu with window scroll
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if($(".contextMenuContainer").length) {
            var $elem = $(".contextMenuContainer").parents(".contextMenuParent");
            var off = $elem.offset();
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            $(".contextMenuContainer").css('top', (off.top + $elem.outerHeight() - scroll) + 'px');
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".contextMenu li", function() {
        var c = $(this).attr("class");

        var title = $(this).closest(".contextMenuParent").find("a").attr("title");

        $(".contextMenuContainer").remove();
    });

});
```

Comment: Awesome, nice solution! I definitely learned something today thanks to you! :) Thx!

Comment: I credited you in my finished project. https://github.com/Eddcapone/burning-series-manager/blob/master/README.md